# Android - TabLayout - Fragments are empty sometimes

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments, tabs, android-recyclerview

I have created an app with a Tabbed Activity. I have 3 Tabs and in the first tab I have added a RecyclerView. At first everything works fine. But when I start the app now, the fragments are empty. Even the fragments of the 2nd and 3rd Tabs are empty, where I only placed a TextView. Here is the code from the MainActivity, it is mainly generated from Android Studio, I only added some code to change the Toolbar title and changed some small things:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private SectionsPagerAdapter mSectionsPagerAdapter;

    private ViewPager mViewPager;
    private Toolbar toolbar;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        toolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        toolbar.setTitle("Pflege");
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        mSectionsPagerAdapter = new SectionsPagerAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) findViewById(R.id.container);
        mViewPager.setAdapter(mSectionsPagerAdapter);

        TabLayout tabLayout = (TabLayout) findViewById(R.id.tabs);
        tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(mViewPager);

        tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon_pflege);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon_dokumentation);
        tabLayout.getTabAt(2).setIcon(R.drawable.tab_icon_probleme);

        tabLayout.addOnTabSelectedListener(new TabLayout.OnTabSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onTabSelected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {
                switch(tab.getPosition()) {
                    case 0:
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(0);
                        toolbar.setTitle("Pflege");
                        break;
                    case 1:
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(1);
                        toolbar.setTitle("Daten");
                        break;
                    case 2:
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(2);
                        toolbar.setTitle("Probleme");
                        break;
                    default:
                        mViewPager.setCurrentItem(tab.getPosition());
                        toolbar.setTitle("Pflege");
                        break;
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onTabUnselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTabReselected(TabLayout.Tab tab) {

            }
        });

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

    public class SectionsPagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

        public SectionsPagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
            super(fm);
        }

        @Override
        public Fragment getItem(int position) {
            switch(position){
                case 0:
                    Tab1Pflege tab1 = new Tab1Pflege();
                    return tab1;
                case 1:
                    Tab2Dokumentation tab2 = new Tab2Dokumentation();
                    return tab2;
                case 2:
                    Tab3Probleme tab3 = new Tab3Probleme();
                    return tab3;
                default:
                    return null;
            }
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            // Show 3 total pages.
            return 3;
        }

        @Override
        public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
            switch (position) {
                case 0:
                    return "Pflege";
                case 1:
                    return "Daten";
                case 2:
                    return "Probleme";
            }
            return null;
        }
    }
}
```

Here is the XML File for the MainActivity. I changed a bit, that the tabs will be placed at the bottom of the screen:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="eis1617.muellerkimmeyer.app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:id="@+id/appbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:paddingTop="@dimen/appbar_padding_top"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay"
        android:background="#3f84dd">

        <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
            android:id="@+id/toolbar"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
            app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|enterAlways"
            app:popupTheme="@style/AppTheme.PopupOverlay" />
    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

    <android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
        android:id="@+id/container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
        android:layout_above="@+id/tabs" />

    <android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="bottom"
        android:elevation="80dp"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme.AppBarOverlay">

        <android.support.design.widget.TabLayout
            android:id="@+id/tabs"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"
            android:clickable="true"
            app:tabGravity="fill"
            app:tabIndicatorHeight="0dp"
            app:tabMode="fixed"
            app:tabBackground="@drawable/tab_color_selector"
            android:background="#3f84dd"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Now here is the fragment for the first tab. It contains the RecyclerView:

```
public class Tab1Pflege extends Fragment {

    private RecyclerView recyclerView;
    private RecyclerView.Adapter rvAdapter;
    private RecyclerView.LayoutManager rvLayoutManager;

    private ArrayList<String> listItems;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_pflege, container, false);

        listItems = new ArrayList<>();
        listItems.add("Test1");
        listItems.add("Test2");
        listItems.add("Test3");

        recyclerView = (RecyclerView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.recyclerView);
        rvLayoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity());
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(rvLayoutManager);
        rvAdapter = new RvAdapter(listItems);
        recyclerView.setAdapter(rvAdapter);

        return rootView;
    }

}
```

And here is the XML File for that tab:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="eis1617.muellerkimmeyer.app.MainActivity">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:id="@+id/recyclerView"

        />

</RelativeLayout>
```

And here the XML file for the list items. There is a TextView on the left and an ImageView on the right:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="50dp"
    android:background="?attr/selectableItemBackground">

    <TextView
        android:text="TextView"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/itemTitle"
        android:layout_marginLeft="21dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="21dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:textSize="20sp" />

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="50dp"
        android:id="@+id/itemImage"
        android:layout_marginRight="11dp"
        android:layout_marginEnd="11dp"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true" />
</RelativeLayout>
```

And finally here is my Adapter class for the RecyclerView:

```
public class RvAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RvAdapter.MyViewHolder> {

    ArrayList<String> listItems;

    public RvAdapter (ArrayList<String> listItems){
        this.listItems = listItems;
    }

    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {

        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.rv_item_layout, null);

        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, final int position) {

        holder.itemTitle.setText(listItems.get(position));
        holder.itemImage.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_keyboard_arrow_right);

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return listItems.size();
    }

    public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{

        TextView itemTitle;
        ImageView itemImage;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView){
            super(itemView);

            itemTitle = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemTitle);
            itemImage = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.itemImage);
        }

    }
}
```

I have already tried to replace "extends FragmentPagerAdapter" in MainActivity with "extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter". But the fragments are still empty. Someone know what could be the problem? Sometimes when I change something for example in the XML file for the list items, it works again. But when I restart the app it didnt work anymore. Looks like it is random if it works or not.

Comment: try to disable instant run if its there and use clean and build option to run your project

Comment: did you manage to find the problem? I am having the same thing

Comment: @Binev the most simple solution I have seen is to call the setOffscreenPageLimit() method. 
viewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(3);//tell the viewpager how many fragments needs to be saved in memory